# alert an src by clicking a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, url, var, src, attr

this is my jquery code; but it gives me (undefined).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.items > tbody > tr').click(function() {
        var src = $(this).find('a[title="View"]').attr('src');
        alert (src)
    });
});
```

the HTML code is :

```
<table class="items">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>
        <a title='View' src="main.php"></a> 
        <a title='find' src="index.php"></a>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please post more html including `.items` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your anchor tags `<a>` are out of `<tr>` family. You have to bring them inside `<td>` so they become children of `<tr>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.items > tbody > tr').click(function() {
        var src = $(this).find('a[title="View"]').attr('src');
        alert (src)
    });
});
```

```css
tr{
  background:#ff8800;
  height:40px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="items">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a title='View' src="main.php"></a> 
          <a title='find' src="index.php"></a>
        <td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your this is out of scope.

Try passing scope into your function like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.items > tbody > tr').click(() => {
        var src = $(this).find('a[title="View"]').attr('src');
        alert (src)
    });
});
```

```css
tr{
  background:#ff8800;
  height:40px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="items">
<tbody>
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>  
          <a title='View' src="main.php"></a> 
          <a title='find' src="index.php"></a>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: See expanded code. This solution most definitely works.